# No module named django.core.urlresovers in django 2.0a1

Tags: django

Have recently upgraded from django 1.11.7 to django 2.0a1 and now cannot import reverse_lazy

```
 File "/home/silasi/Deprojecto/eljogo/jogos/views.py", line 8, in <module>
  from django.core.urlresolvers import reverse_lazy
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'django.core.urlresolvers'
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In Django 2.0 you must import:
`from django.urls import reverse_lazy`

Comment: why is this different from my answer?

Answer (score 9):

Since version 1.10 `django.core.urlresolvers` was deprecated, change the import to

```
from django.urls import reverse_lazy
```

[more information about 1.10 version](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/releases/1.10/#id3),

[more info about `django.urls`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/urlresolvers/#module-django.urls)